# logs froom Nginx to rsyslog

Tags: nginx, logging, rsyslog

I want to send logs from nginx to local rsyslog via udp (and then send from local rsyslog to remote syslog-ng => redis => logstash, etc.)

my nginx virtual host configuration contains the following line **/etc/nginx/sites-enable/01_myserver.conf**

```
access_log syslog:server=127.0.0.1:415,facility=local4,severity=notice main;
```

my configuration **/etc/rsyslog.conf**

```
$PreserveFQDN on
$MainMsgQueueTimeoutEnqueue 0
$MaxMessageSize 12k
$template LongTagForwardFormat,"<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg%"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$ActionForwardDefaultTemplate LongTagForwardFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local3.none;local2.none;local4.none;local5.none;local6.none;local0.none;local1.none /var/log/messages

authpriv.* /var/log/secure
mail.* /var/log/maillog
cron.* /var/log/cron
uucp,news.crit /var/log/spooler
local7.* /var/log/boot.log
```

my configuration is **/etc/rsyslog.d/server_for_nginx.conf**

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 415
$FileCreateMode 0640
$RepeatedMsgReduction off
$AllowedSender UDP, 127.0.0.1
```

but I don't see nginx logs being sent to rsyslog port 415... checking with `tcpdump -vv -n -X port 415`

What am I doing wrong and what is my mistake?

Comment: Are you using any host-based firewall and what OS are you using? Also, you're not checking for *UDP* packages, it should look something like this `tcpdump -i eth0 udp port 415 -vv -X`

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. I am using rocky linux 8 and iptables. nginx and rsyslog are on the same server

I will try your suggestion

Comment: Okay, be sure to add that information to your question, as I for example thought 127.0.0.1 is just an example IP. Also this question isn't really programming related and therefore doesn't belong on SO. It will be much better off (and probably receive more attention) on a different SE site like [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).